# Return value from mongo js script file called from java

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb

I am calling a MongoDB JavaScript Script file from java as below

```
String jsCode = readFromMongoScript("/path/to/script.js");
```

jsCode contains javascript in string format.

as the next step i am trying to capture the response returned from jscode.

```
CommandResult resultSet = getMongoConnection().getDB(dbName).doEval(jsCode);
System.out.println("Resultset: " + resultSet);
```

but i am getting response in the log as show below:

`Resultset: { "retval" :  null  , "ok" : 1.0}`

Hence please help,

> How to return data from Mongo Js Script file to Java
>
> How to read/accesses it in Java?

Comment: [`eval`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/eval/#dbcmd.eval) is deprecated and has been for several minor releases now. This means it **will be removed** and therefore you should not be writing any new code that depends on it. In fact any legacy code using server-side execution of JavaScript in this way really should be re-written as a matter of priority. Whatever purpose you "think" you need this for will be better served by wring in you implementation language of choice ( here it's Java ) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after little more research i solved my problem.

1. provided a explicit `return` statement in the Mongo Js Script solved the problem and the resulting output is:

`Resultset: { "retval" : true , "ok" : 1.0}`